# sas relative frequencies by group

Tags: sas, frequency-distribution

I have a categorical variable, say SALARY_GROUP, and a group variable, say COUNTRY. I would like to get the relative frequency of SALARY_GROUP within COUNTRY in SAS. Is it possible to get it by proc SUMMARY or proc means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS--calculating mean by multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444022/sas-calculating-mean-by-multiple-groups)

Comment: Why not use proc freq?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explore proc tabulate and a counter variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can calculate the relative frequency of a categorical variable using both `Proc Means` and `Proc Summary`. For both procs you have to:

-Specify NWAY in the proc statement,

-Specify in the Class statement your categorical fields,

-Specify in the Var  statement your response or numeric field.

Example below is for [proc means](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146728.htm):

Dummy Data:

```
/*Dummy Data*/
data work.have;
input Country $ Salary_Group $ Value;
datalines;
USA Group1 100
USA Group1 100
GBR Group1 100
GBR Group1 100
USA Group2 20
USA Group2 20
GBR Group2 20
GBR Group1 100
;
run;
```

Code:

```
*Calculating Frequncy and saving output to table sg_means*/
proc means data=have n nway ;
class Country Salary_Group;
var Value;
output out=sg_means n=frequency;
run;
```

Output Table:

```
Country=GBR Salary_Group=Group1 _TYPE_=3 _FREQ_=3 frequency=3 
Country=GBR Salary_Group=Group2 _TYPE_=3 _FREQ_=1 frequency=1 
Country=USA Salary_Group=Group1 _TYPE_=3 _FREQ_=2 frequency=2 
Country=USA Salary_Group=Group2 _TYPE_=3 _FREQ_=2 frequency=2
```

Comment: Thanks Momo but I see absolute frequencies here

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you want / relative frequency based on my  dummy data? I will update my code.